# .MYD and .MYI files are missing in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

.MYD and .MYI files in mysql database are missing. Is there any possibility to restore my data.

Comment: use a backup. You take regular backups, right?

Comment: It is on my local system.

Comment: that's not what I asked